Microsoft Access Database Engine Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user
We are getting the error - An OLEDB record is available. Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine Description: "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user" while executing the SSIS package from SSMS.
The package is executing successfully from Visual Studio.
Our SQL server version: sql server 2016 64-bit
SSMS : 2016
We are getting the error - An OLEDB record is available. Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine Description: "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user" while executing the SSIS package from SSMS.
From visual studio, the package is executing successfully.
We have already tried below

Install 32- & 64-bit Microsoft Access database Engine 2016. Tried with only 32-Bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 as well.
Run the package with 32-bit runtime from SSMS.
Connection String we are using: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=Excel Path;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=NO";
Verified the driver exists in odbc settings (C:\Windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe)
Verified existence of registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 and verified it had read access for users and administrators.
6.Verified existence of C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE16\ACEOLEDB.DLL and verified folder and its contents had read access for users and administrators.
provided the user access on excel PATH

everytime we are getting this same error.
Anyone has faced this problem before and any fix ?
